# Do we really have free-will?

Tags: free-will

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If God controls our decisions, does this mean we don't have free will?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/if-god-controls-our-decisions-does-this-mean-we-dont-have-free-will)

The bible says that God is omniscient, he knows about you even before you were born, he knew that Adam would sin. That made me think about the question, `Do I really have free-will?`.
If God already knows that I will go to hell how is it possible that I could choose the way of heaven?

There is an example that quite matches this question. A person offers to you a coin, but this peron knows the future, he knows whether if you are going to accept or not, when you have finally made your choice, how could you had the free will if he already knew if you were going to accept it or not?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I did close this question because it's a duplicate, but that should not by any means discourage you from posting more questions. I hope you'll stick around and contribute! :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, should have looked around!