# Are the people involved in killing Jesus innocent

Tags: prophecy

Are the people in the bible innocent of killing Jesus if the crucifiction was already prophisized. Would God need people to play certain roles like judas to help fulfill his prophesy. If judas was needed to help fulfill the crucifiction of Christ,wouldn't that make him a forced traitor?someone would have to play the role of a traitor. If there was no crucifiction there would be no salvation.

Comment: Hugely related: [If God controls our decisions does this mean we don't have free will?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/if-god-controls-our-decisions-does-this-mean-we-dont-have-free-will)

Comment: Besides Judas, maybe you can explain who you mean by 'people' and what you mean by 'innocent' or guilty of what for that matter. It might be best to limit your question to Judas and first establish his guilt.

Comment: A related thing to look at is when God talks about the nations he used to judge Israel in the OT. Even though they were his tools, he promised to send other nations to judge them for the evil they did.

Comment: @vera-kasayulie: given Jesus said forgive them (for they know not what they do) I think they are safe, given Jesus' forgiveness - of all people.

Comment: @vera-kasayulie: "wouldn't that make him a forced traitor?" I think this may be a different question...

Answer (score 3):

My take (Baptist - leaning toward free will) is that they are not innocent, and that they willingly made the choices they made.  In fact, we are all sinners in some respect, but can all be forgiven through Jesus:

> [Romans 3:23 NKJV] 23 for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,
>
> [Romans 6:23 NKJV] 23 For the wages of sin [is] death, but the gift of God [is] eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.
>
> [Romans 5:8 NKJV] 8 But God demonstrates His own love toward us, in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us.
>
> [Romans 10:9-10 NKJV] 9 that if you confess with your mouth the Lord Jesus and believe in your heart that God has raised Him from the dead, you will be saved. 10 For with the heart one believes unto righteousness, and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation.

My understanding is that for the people involved in Jesus's crucifixion, God knew these people would choose to do the things they did, and He used it in His plan.  However, I do not believe God forced Judas to betray Jesus.  However, He did know what Judas was doing, used it in His plan:

> [Matthew 26:31 NKJV] 31 Then Jesus said to them, "All of you will be made to stumble because of Me this night, for it is written: 'I will strike the Shepherd, And the sheep of the flock will be scattered.'
>
> [John 13:26-27 NKJV] 26 Jesus answered, "It is he to whom I shall give a piece of bread when I have dipped [it]." And having dipped the bread, He gave [it] to Judas Iscariot, [the son] of Simon. 27 Now after the piece of bread, Satan entered him. Then Jesus said to him, "What you do, do quickly."

Interestingly enough, Jesus even asked for forgiveness for the people who were against Him when He was on the cross!

> [Luke 23:33-34 NKJV] 33 And when they had come to the place called Calvary, there they crucified Him, and the criminals, one on the right hand and the other on the left. 34 Then Jesus said, "Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they do." And they divided His garments and cast lots.

In summary, it appears the people involved in Jesus's crucifixion were not innocent, but even they could be forgiven!