# What are the Catholic arguments for God having a free will?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, will-of-god, sovereignty

I have noticed a version of this question ([Does God have free will?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/901/does-god-have-free-will) ) however I would like to ask it in a slightly different way:

What are the most significant biblical and other (patristic, scholastic) arguments for God's free will from the Catholic perspective?

Comment: Are you asking what governs his actions.  For example, He does not violate his Nature, but has free will within that framework?

Answer (score 3):

St. Thomas Aquinas addresses this in his [*Summa Theologica* I q. 19 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP019.html#FPQ19A10THEP1) article, "[Whether God has free-will?](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP019.html#FPQ19A10THEP1)" He answers (c.):

> We have free-will with respect to what we will not of necessity or of natural instinct. For our will to be happy does not appertain to free-will, but to natural instinct. Hence other animals, that are moved to act by natural instinct, are not said to be moved by free-will. Since then God necessarily wills His own goodness, but other things not necessarily, as shown above ([a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP019.html#FPQ19A3THEP1)), He has free will with respect to what He does not necessarily will.

Comment: Great reference, thanks. However, does it mean that e.g. the procession of the Holy Spirit in Trinity is not an act of free will?

Comment: @KarelMacek [God's essence is His existence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP003.html#FPQ3A4THEP1), [the Divine Relations in God _are_ His essence](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP028.html#FPQ28A2THEP1), and His existence is absolutely necessary (cf. his ["third way" of proving God's existence](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/FP/FP002.html#FPQ2A3THEP1)). Thus, because "He has free will [only] with respect to what He does not will of necessity," He is not free _not_ to be triune (or to be anything that isn't His nature). "I am Who am" (Ex. 3:14); viz., God is God and must be God.

Comment: @KarelMacek It's analogous to how it's impossible for the blessed in heaven, although they have freewill, not to love God.